# Angularjs - formatting a table with ng-repeat where a column does not have any data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table as shown in the plunkr example.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8KK9JdlBqOYX78ywmLYN?p=preview

In this case, no data exists for 'east' or 'west' in $scope.siteData in the controller, but for 'north', 'south' and 'central'.

The data for 'central' is showing under 'east'

How do I display empty column under 'east' and 'west' when ng-repeat does not have any data.

Here is my html

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>                 
                            <tr>
                                <th >Month</th>
                                <th >North</th>
                                <th >South</th>
                                <th >East</th>
                                <th >West</th>
                                <th >Central</th>
                                <th >Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="items in siteData" >
                            <tr  >
                                <td>
                                    {{items.monthYear | date:'MMMM - yyyy' }}
                                </td>
                                <td ng-repeat="region in items.regions | filter: {regionName: 'North'}">
                                    {{region.capacity.allocated }} / {{region.capacity.capacity}}
                                </td>
                                <td ng-repeat="region in items.regions | filter: {regionName: 'South'}">
                                    {{region.capacity.allocated }} / {{region.capacity.capacity}}                               
                                </td>
                                <td ng-repeat="region in items.regions | filter: {regionName: 'East'}">
                                    {{region.capacity.allocated }} / {{region.capacity.capacity}}
                                </td>
                                <td ng-repeat="region in items.regions | filter: {regionName: 'West'}">
                                    {{region.capacity.allocated}} / {{region.capacity.capacity}}
                                </td>
                                <td ng-repeat="region in items.regions | filter: {regionName: 'Central'}">
                                    {{region.capacity.allocated}} / {{region.capacity.capacity}}
                                </td>                                   
                            </tr>                                               
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Sorry about the vague title and description. I'm not so good with words.

Comment: Why are you using ng-repeat? Do you expect there to be multiple North regions? It seems you are only using the ng-repeat so you can use the filter. If so, there is a much easier way to do that. Let me know, and I will try to explain further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect it would be more efficient to use a filter function than a lot of ngRepeats.

You can add a data matching function to the controller:

```
$scope.findData = function(data, filter) {

    record = data.regions.filter(function(v, i){
        if(v.regionName === filter) return true;
    }); // returns an array of matches

    // get first item in array if exists else return empty string
    return (record.length > 0) ? record[0].capacity.allocated + ' / ' + record[0].capacity.capacity : '';
};
```

And then replace your HTML with:

```
<td>
   {{ findData(items, 'North') }}
</td>
<td>
   {{ findData(items, 'South') }}
</td>
<td>
   {{ findData(items, 'East') }}
</td>
<td>
   {{ findData(items, 'West') }}
</td>
<td>
   {{ findData(items, 'Central') }}
</td>
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/qZsIQKSwUwf4UEud5wxc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using ng-repeat so you can use filter, you can just add the ng-repeat on a `<span>` inside the `<td>` element.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
<td>
    <span ng-repeat="region in items.regions | filter: {regionName: 'East'}">{{region.capacity.allocated }} / {{region.capacity.capacity}}
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: this will also work but I don't need to use so many ng-repeats, hence why I have accepted the other answer

Comment: Exactly, avoid those ng-repeats unless you expect multiple items.